# How do I configure Eclipse to work on Qt-based applications in a subversion tree?

Tags: eclipse, svn, qt

Most of the work being done at my company is Qt-based C++, and it's all checked into a Subversion repository. Until now, all work on the codebase has been done purely with nano, or perhaps Kate. Being new here, I would like to take advantage of setting up Eclipse -properly- to edit my local copy of the tree. I have the CDT "version" of Eclipse, and the Qt integration, and the Subclipse module. At this point, though, I don't know what to do. Do I "import" the projects into an Eclipse-controlled workspace? Do I edit them in place? Nothing I've tried to do gets Eclipse to recognize that the "project" is a Qt application, so that I can get the integration working.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a new QT project in eclipse, then switch perspectives to subclipse and simply do a SVN checkout into the new eclipse project. You should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've been playing around with this idea, and it has some merit. I can switch to the "SVN Project Exploring" perspective (which I hadn't noticed before), and do a checkout from the head of the sub-project I want. I get a nice SVN-linked copy of the tree in my Eclipse workspace for editing. Eclipse even "understands" the classes, and can do completion on methods and such. However, I still can't get Eclipse to understand that the project is a "QT Gui" project, such that I could view the properties, and control the linking of the various Qt libraries and the like. By extension, it also doesn't understand how to build my project, like it would be able to do if I had created an empty Qt Gui project from scratch. How do I get this part working?

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same situation at work (with CVS instead of subversion and the rest of the team using KDevelop but that's no big deal). Just start a new Qt Gui project using the Qt - Eclipse integration features and then remove all the auto generated files. Now using the "Team" features of eclipse and choose to share your project, enter the path to the repository and you 're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the project. It will ask you some options like if you want to start with a blank project, or want to use the tree to make a new project. Choose the latter and you should be ok :). It seems to work for me with Ganymed and subversive(not sure about subclipse and i don't remember.) :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get this to work was to check out the project with eclipse and then copy over the .project and .cdtproject files from another Qt-project. Then do a refresh on the project. This is a horrible hack but it gets you started. 
You might need to define another builder for 'make'.

Answer (score 0):

Second nikolavp - Checkout, and mark the option to use the new project wizard, then select Qt project.  I've done this (with ganymede) and it successfully finds everything and builds correctly.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1. go to the svn-view and add the repository location for your project
2. check out the project some temporary location with svn or any client you like
3. choose 'File->Import...' and say 'Qt->Qt project'
4. browse to the location of the *.pro file, select and hit the OK-Button
5. you are in the game with an appropriate Qt-project and Subversion Access for that project

Answer (score 0):

I would say the same as the last one,
but instead of the two first steps I would set up the Qt-Eclipse integration: 
[Qt-Eclipse integration](http://www.qtsoftware.com/developer/eclipse-integration) before looking for the *.pro file.